# Is this is a right way to make java.text.DateFormat threadSafe?

Tags: java, date

I'm working on a project where the date format is kept as a static Utility field as shown below

```
public static final SimpleDateFormat MM_DD_YYYY = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_DEFAULT, Locale.US);
```

Luckily FindBugs started giving the warning that the DateFormats are inherently unsafe for multithreaded use.

To remove these warnings one of the developer in the team changed the field access to private and provided a public accessor function like this

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat MM_DD_YYYY = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_DEFAULT, Locale.US);
public static SimpleDateFormat getMmDdYyyy() {
    return MM_DD_YYYY;
}
```

Magically FindBugs warnings disappeared!
My question is Doesn't the both snippets of code are semantically same?

If yes Why not the Findbugs showing any warnings in the second case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's *better* in that having public fields is almost always a bad idea, particularly for mutable objects.

However, it's *definitely* still not thread-safe. Two threads could absolutely call the method and end up using the formatter at the same time.

You could create your own wrapper object (possibly still extending `DateFormat`; I'm not sure offhand) which serialized requests and possibly had a "pool" of underlying formats. Or you could use Joda Time or `java.time`, both of which are much better date/time APIs to start with, and have thread-safe formatters.

Another alternative would be to just have two static methods, `parseMonthDayYear` and `formatMonthDayYear`, and let *them* take care of thread safety.

Comment: Why not just *synchronize* on `getMmDdYyyy()` ?

Comment: @TheLostMind: As I was just replying to your answer, that doesn't help. You'd still end up with multiple threads having reference to the same "thread-unsafe" object. You wouldn't be serializing the *dangerous* part.

Comment: Yep.. I realized that once I got downvoted :).. *synchronization* won't help Threads can still access that instance.. A wrapper ought to do the trick.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

the best and faster way to use DateFormat in a thead safe context is to use it in ThreadLocal. it will insure you one instance per thread.

like this :

```
 private ThreadLocal<DateFormat> df = new ThreadLocal<DateFormat> () {

  @Override
  public DateFormat get() {
   return super.get();
  }

  @Override
  protected DateFormat initialValue() {
   return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd");
  }

  @Override
  public void remove() {
   super.remove();
  }

  @Override
  public void set(DateFormat value) {
   super.set(value);
  }

 };

 public Date convertStringToDate(String dateString) throws ParseException {
  return df.get().parse(dateString);
 }
```

look at this link for more details and benchmarks:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/07/java-best-practices-dateformat-in.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use ThreadLocal:

```
private static ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> format = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>() {
    @Override
    protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_DEFAULT, Locale.US);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe since it uses inner mutable state on processing. Making it `final static` won't help because operations will be still performed on that single instance, in which through that state threads will interact.

Solution: return defensive copy:

```
private static final DateFormat MM_DD_YYYY = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_DEFAULT, Locale.US);

public static DateFormat getMmDdYyyy() {
    return (DateFormat) MM_DD_YYYY.clone();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an experiment, but I wonder if an additional solution might be to create a `SimpleDateFormat` subclass that overrides all `set*()` methods with no-op implementations, and use that?  It seems to me that the `SimpleDateFormat` thread safety issues come from the format's mutability. (I can't imagine there being any statefulness in the course of actual `format()` calls.) So if you are using a `SimpleDateFormat` that you know will never change, maybe use this subclass instead?  You could even pass it a `SimpleDateFormat` instance in the constructor. This would be sort of an immutable decorator, a la what you do with the `java.util.Collections.unmodifiable*` methods.

The plus is you would not have to ensure having an instance per thread, or have synchronization overhead. The minus (I think) is that this might not satisfy FindBugs (I don't have it so I can't try it.)

### Update - why this won't work

It turns out this won't work. As @biziclop pointed out in the comments below, there actually **is** mutable internal state being used within the `format()` methods - a shared instance of `Calendar`. [Here is the link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.java#SimpleDateFormat.format%28java.util.Date%2Cjava.lang.StringBuffer%2Cjava.text.Format.FieldDelegate%29) @biziclop provided showing what's going on in the `SimpleDateFormat` source. I will not speculate on why the implementors did this, but I can say for sure that even `format()` is stateful and thus my plan will not work.

Comment: You'd think so, but I've got [bad news](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.java#SimpleDateFormat.format%28java.util.Date%2Cjava.lang.StringBuffer%2Cjava.text.Format.FieldDelegate%29) for you. Take a look at the linked code and how it uses the shared `calendar` field. Sigh.

Comment: The problem with SDF is that if 2 threads for example parse strings, they interact through inner state. Synchronization nor making it immutable won't help.

Comment: @biziclop egads, why did they do that?  Thanks for catching and showing this!  Will edit right away.

Comment: I really wouldn't want to guess. :)

Comment: @sparc_spread bad design, the same as `Date` class is mutable.